# Failed to start MongoDB server. dbexit: rc: 48 error in mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I updated MongoDB and now I am getting this error. I even tried to stop and start the MongoDB service again but still it is showing the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I start mongodb server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771136/why-cant-i-start-mongodb-server)

Answer (score -1):

Check the error. If the error has "Address already in use for socket ...", you should have something else using mongodb port.